# Find the positive integers $a,b,p$ if $p^2=b^2+a$ and $p^2\mid a^2+b$.

Tags: number-theory

Let $a,b\ (a\neq b)$ be positive integers, and $p$ is prime number, such
$$b^2+a=p^2,\dfrac{a^2+b}{b^2+a}\in Z$$

Find $p,a,b$

I have prove $a>b$,because $$a^2+b>b^2+a\Longrightarrow a>b$$

Comment: Chase down consequences pf $p$ dividing $a^2+b$.

Answer (score 4):

The following solution is for the condition $p=b^2+a$ since this was the question prior to an edit.

$b^2+a|a^2+b$ is equivalent to $b^2+a|(a-b)(a+b-1)$.

But since $p$ is prime we must have, $p|a-b$ or $p|a+b-1$.

But $a-b < b^2+a$ and $a+b-1 < b^2+a$

So, no solutions in positive integers.

Comment: Did you mean $(a-b)^2<b^2+a$ or something similar?

Comment: @Element118, no i just meant $a-b < b^2+a$ which is obvious for positive integers.

Comment: How does $a-b<b^2+a$ show that there are no solutions?

Comment: @Element118, because we are getting $p|a-b$ or $p|a+b-1$ which means $a-b \geq p=b^2+a$ or $a+b-1 \geq p = b^2+a$. But since we have $a-b < b^2+a$ and $a+b-1 > b^2+a$

Comment: @MosBlack,Hello,sorry before this problem  I have something forgot, I have edit it, This condtion is  $p^2=b^2+a$

Comment: @Element118, I solved the question for $b^2+a=p$. Did i misread it or was the question edited?

Comment: @MosBlack I would recommend copying the original question and placing it in a new question and self-answering it with your current answer.

Answer (score 0):

This answer eventually uses @Mosblack's idea. But I think it has some thing useful here. We have: $a^2 + b = np \Rightarrow (p-b^2)^2 + b = np\Rightarrow b^4 - 2pb^2 + p^2 + b - np = 0\Rightarrow p \mid b^4+b=b(1+b^3)=b(1+b)(1-b+b^2)$. From the condition, $p > b, p > b^2 + 1 > b+1$, thus $p\mid (1-b+b^2)\Rightarrow b^2-b+1 = mp \Rightarrow b^2 = b - 1 + mp\Rightarrow p= a+b^2 = a + b-1 + mp \Rightarrow b - a + 1 = (m-1)p \geq 0 \Rightarrow b \geq a-1$. From this you can see that $b = a -1$ or $b \geq a$. The latter case has no solution, and the former is easy to handle. In fact, you have $b = a - 1 \Rightarrow \dfrac{a^2+b}{b^2+a} = \dfrac{a^2+a-1}{a^2-a+1}= 1 + \dfrac{2(a-1)}{a^2-a+1}$. Since $p = a^2-a+1, a^2-a+1 = 2$ or $a^2-a+1 \mid (a- 1)$. In both cases you can get to the bottom of it.

**Note**: I think this solution answers a different question: $b^2 + a = p$ instead of $b^2+a = p^2$. But it is relevant here as well.